# Cannot open a file using a Powerbuilder .NET web service

Tags: xml, web-services, iis-7, powerbuilder

I am using PB 11.5 to deploy a .NET web service which I am trying to test on the server before it is used. This WS loads a blob from the databasbe into an Image file, and saves it locally. Later on I would use a third party tool to further manipulate this file to a pdf. This process works just fine on my local machine but It seems to get stack during the open command of the file:

```
li_FileNum = FileOpen(is_Openfilename[li_fileindex], StreamMode!, Write!, Shared!, Replace!)
```

I am getting a return of -1. Loading the blob from the database was successfull, as I can see its size returned.
I am not sure if this is a permission issue or something else. The Folder which I am trying to open the file has permissions setup for everyone. The Web Server is running IIS 7.0 with Windows Server 2008 R2.

I am testing the WS using the IE test page and rendering the function I need passing an initial value.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Shai

Comment: Did you checked that the `is_Openfilename[li_fileindex]` is a valid path for a file?

Comment: Yes. The Path is correct. your response got me thinking and I added a debug check to see if I can find a file in that directory. FileExist(fileName) returned False after I manually placed a file in that directory. I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: It could be an ACL problem. Can you check if the profile that is owning the running process has access to the folder like you?

Comment: The Profile/Identity that runs this web service has administrator rights.

Comment: Use Process Monitor (SysInternals) to see where the file activities are happening. This may be stretching the analogy, but Web Forms maps file accesses to session-specific directories. This may be what is happening to your file requests.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Tried it but it didn't help. It does show a great deal of information tough.

Comment: Posting my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out late Friday afternoon with the help of a trusted co-worker. We added Folder Permissions to the groups IIS_IUSRS and IUSR on the Web Server. I was able to finally open the file on the Server and could locate it deep down even more withing the virtual path on the Application Folder. I changed My open File code to not use a Path: li_FileNum = FileOpen(is_Openfilename[li_fileindex], StreamMode!, Write!, Shared!, Replace!) and was able to locate the file at : From application Folder \ws_ios_transfer_root\file\session_*webservice*_\c